# Should I max out my walls before going to town hall 9?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've maxed out all my defenses and I have 55 lvl 8 walls and the rest lvl 7, should I go to town hall 9 right away or finish up my walls?

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your defenses is maxed out then you should upgrade to town hall 9, level 7 wall is pretty good and it can handle your base ( if you stay at gold league you don't need to upgrade your walls to level 8 first )

By the way in town hall level 9 every defense needs 5 or more days to upgrade so you can upgrade your walls there.

I assumed your troops is maxed out too, since you upgraded your defenses.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is unnecessary as they cost too much to upgrade. If you are farming I would go straight ahead to the next level. If you are not, make sure you have put level 8 walls on the critical points of your base, then move on to the next town hall.

Answer (score 0):

You prolly don't need the walls now but the loot penalty for upgrading your town hall is going to make it harder later on

Comment: The loot penalty of upgrading to TH9 is miniscule. However the loot penalty to TH10 is enough to be considered, I plan on completely maxing out TH9 including walls and heroes before upgrading.